# Argument that closure of identity in topological group is normal subgroup.

Tags: topological-groups

Let H be the closure of $\{e\}$, where $e$ is the identity element of a topological group $G$. We know that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. We want to prove that $H$ is normal subgroup of $G$. In Valenza's "Fourier Analysis on Number Fields" the proof is as follows:

"Since $\{e\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ so is its closure $H$. Moreover, it is the smallest closed subgroup of $G$ containing $e$ and therefore normal, **since each conjugate of $H$ is likewise a closed subgroup containing $e$**."

The bold argument above is the one that I don't understand. I can see that for every $g\in G$, $gHg^{-1}$ is a closed subgroup (because traslations are homeomorphisms and $H$ is closed) and that implies that $H\leq gHg^{-1}$, but I don't have any idea about how to get $gHg^{-1}\leq H$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you worry about $H\le g^{-1}Hg$?

Comment: I'm just saying that the argument in the book seems to me that only implies that statement.

Comment: @HeMan: Take that "inequality", and multiply both sides by $g^{-1}$ on the left, and $g$ on the right (or whatever it takes to isolate $H$ on the right).

Answer (score 2):

The conjugation $x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$ is a group automorphism and also a homeomorphism. Thus if $H$ is a closed subgroup, also $g^{-1}Hg$ is a closed subgroup.

Now if $H$ is the closure of $\{e\}$, it is contained in every closed subgroup of $G$. Now $g^{-1}Hg$ is a closed subgroup, so $H\subseteq g^{-1}Hg$, for every $g$. Using $g^{-1}$ we conclude that $H\subseteq gHg^{-1}$, which implies $g^{-1}Hg\subseteq H$.

The argument above just uses the fact that each conjugate of $H$ is a closed subgroup, which is the statement you're worrying about.

Comment: How do you get the last implicación?

Comment: @HeMan Apply conjugation by $g$ to both sides.